# how to update default custom property of attribute in gutenberg

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm developing my first plugin in Gutenberg. What I've done is hook into a filter hook

addFilter(
"blocks.registerBlockType",
"my-first-block/add-attributes",
addAttributes
);

where inside I extended some props:

```
const addAttributes = (settings) => {
    if (typeof settings.attributes !== "undefined") {
        settings.attributes = Object.assign(settings.attributes, {
            my_visibility_options: {
                type: "object",
                default: {
                    checkScreen: {
                        label: "Screen",
                        enabled:true,
                        priority: 1,
                        active: false,
                        breakpoints: {
                            desktop: {
                                hide: false,
                            },
                            tablet: {
                                hide: false,
                            },
                            mobile: {
                                hide: false,
                            },
                        },
                    },
                   
                },
            },

        });
    }

    return settings;
};
```

Then I hooked up to another hook:

```
addFilter(
  "editor.BlockEdit",
  "my-custom-block/with-advance-controls",
  withInspectorControl
);
```

where I extended some functionality by inserting components inside the InspectorControls.

I created an admin page where I want to give the possibility to activate or deactivate these features, basically I should override the "enabled" property based on the options chosen in the backend admin page.
Is there a possibility to intercept my_visibility_options or do I have to overwrite the data?